# How would you seal a hole in an HDPE container that's in -20C environment

Tags: materials, temperature, seals, adhesive

I have a temperature sensor in a -20C freezer.  The probe is going into a bottle filled with propylene glycol solution.  I want to seal the hole where the probe is inserted into the bottle.

What's a good sealant for this?

Comment: put the probe down through the neck of the bottle.

Comment: still need to seal it somehow though - i want to make sure the contents don't leak out if the bottle is tilted on it's side

Comment: Does the lid of the bottle need to be HDPE also?

Comment: That's what the container came with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bonding to HDPE is very difficult. A few adhesives developed fairly recently do ok in some applications, but that kind of cooling will likely cause them to fail.

Instead, I'd recommend a mechanical seal. I would (and often have for this exact purpose) use a [bulkhead fitting](https://www.google.com/search?q=bulkhead%20fitting&oq=bulkhead%20fitting&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2617j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to seal against the wall and an instrument fitting, aka [compression tube fitting](https://www.google.com/search?ei=USQYW8zOMKiS0gLz-4rQDg&q=compression%20tube%20fitting&oq=compression%20tube%20fitting&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i30k1l9.4720.5061.0.5935.5.5.0.0.0.0.176.278.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.1.176....0.A-ShHQH8myE) to seal against the temperature sensor.

Comment: This one is good like a round rubber band you stretch through a hole or an ear plug.

Answer (score 1):

Try this stuff. It's about as good as it gets off the shelf.

[3M™ Scotch-Weld™ Structural Plastic Adhesive DP8005](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/3M-Scotch-Weld-Structural-Plastic-Adhesive-DP8005/?N=5002385+3293241357&rt=rud)

Comment: This adhesive will not bond to HDPE :-(

Comment: Yes it will. This from the King Starboard site - "Products like 3M’s 5200 work well as a water sealing caulk but will not adhere King StarBoard® to itself or other materials in a permanent structural bond. It is preferable to mechanically fasten or weld King StarBoard®, but when an adhesive is necessary you can use a product called Lord 7542-AB, or 3M’s **Scotch-Weld DP-8005**, or Chem-Set™ 6105 Polyolefin Bonder." http://www.kingplastic.com/using-adhesive-with-king-starboard-2/

Comment: 3M is [pretty convinced it will](https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/79749O/3m-scotch-weld-structural-plastic-adhesive-dp-8005.pdf), but DP8010 looks like it might be a better suited product, and 3M calls it a 'Key Product'.

Comment: Try it, see how long the "bond" lasts :-)

Comment: This family of adhesives works much better for flush surfaces, as you'll find in the product literature. It basically doesn't work to seal gaps around random misfit shapes.

Comment: @ericksonla You are correct there. It isn't intended as a gap filler. And there is some surface prep required for best results, so you want access to a nice, neat surface.

Answer (score 1):

JB Water weld works very well for me in many applications like this. It sets under water and is not brittle. I built a lip for a water pump that eroded away. Please let us know what you went with?

[image]

Comment: Ended up going with a container with glass beads instead of a liquid.  That eliminated the whole problem :)

Comment: @MishaM Can you put that as an answers on the process?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest buying extra caps/stoppers and drill a close-fitting hole. If the caps (and your probe/wires can take it), perhaps use some hot-melt glue for a mechanical seal.

Answer (score 0):

You may actually get your best bet by encasing the entire thing in [shrink wrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrink_wrap) (depending upon the size of the bottle).

Shrink wrap is typically made of LDPE.  Due to the low density, the LDPE has many sites where it can still [cross-link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-link) upon itself.  Heating the wrap begins this reaction, and as the material cross-links, it shrinks to form HDPE.  This shrinking action forms a good seal.  In the area of the hole, additional heating could be applied until the LDPE and HDPE entered a plastic state, welding the two materials together.

Other methods, such as acrylics, work well, but this would insure similar chemical resistance inside and outside the freezer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided to use a bottle filled with glass beads.  This provided the necessary thermal stabilization and it has the added benefit of working below -50C.